# Show picker view with user selected photos only

Tags: ios, assets, phpicker, photosui

iOS 14 introduced the new PHPicker where users can select which photos the app is allowed to access the assets.

How can I present the picker view with only the allowed photos visible.

Comment: I also want to know, can't find anything related, yet all the big techs are doing it. this is also asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64258776/how-can-i-display-only-limited-photos-with-phpickerviewcontroller/65025110#65025110